# Angular - Return XML data from server

Tags: angular

I am creating XML data on the server side and sending to my Angular client to save as xml file. But for some reason in the httpClient.post method I get error. Dont understand what is the reason. In the browser console I see the XML data in the Response but for some reason it is not printing the data. I will appreciate help to debug issue.Below is my client code.

Service class

```
public createXML(data:IJob)
{
    console.log("createXML - POST data to server: ", data);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(environment.restUrl + "/createXML/",data)
    .pipe(
      tap((data) => console.log(data)),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

Component class

```
createXML(data:IJob):void{
  this.coreService.createXML(data).subscribe(
    (data: Response) => {
      console.log('XML file',data);
      this.downloadFile(data.text(), 'lot', 'gtin');
    }, (err: any) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the default type of your response is `JSON`, you need to set the response as `text`

In order to achieve this you have to:

```js
public createXML(data:IJob)
{
    console.log("createXML - POST data to server: ", data);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(
      environment.restUrl + "/createXML/",
      data, 
      {
        responseType: "text" // this is 
      }
     ).pipe(
      tap((data) => console.log(data)),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

For more information you see [how to make a POST request](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request)